# What version of eclipse to use

Tags: android, eclipse, version

After using Aptana Studio 2 for a while I decided to get rid of it (Which was hard enough, because there's no uninstall option really) and start using eclipse.

When I went to the download section of the website I got confused by the options, therefor my question.

I program/develop/write code in the following languages:

- Web development front end (html, css, js, xml, etc.)
- Web development back end (php, sql)
- Java (just java and java for android)
- php => Zend framework (I used to have aptana set up for it nicely)

So which version do I get?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this comparison:

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

this should give you an impression which version you need

tip: you should also consider [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) IDE.

Comment: Had seen that but because of the many abbreviations I did not recognize the direction of which I should be reading it. After seeing it again I do understand it, so why not just use the top one which supports everything. Too heavy?

Comment: you have to read it the other way ;) the column shows what is included in the package... then there are projects -> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index_project.php like PDT for web dev -> http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/ -> at the end you can compose your requirements also by adding single plugins

Comment: Still find it hard to figure out, however the Java EE version seems to do the Job.